# Postgresql pg_dump, doesnt work well on dumping and restore schema

Tags: postgresql

I use code belows for dump a specific schema, before dumped it has 4 views on those schema.

```
# pg_dump -U username -h host -n schema_name > some_schema.dump
```

Then I restore it with psql tools

```
# \i /path/to/mydump/some_schema.dump
```

After psql finish his restore process , i just only got 3 views, i have no idea where the 1 views go. i use postgresql 8.3 on ubuntu karmic.

Thanks.

Comment: It might be me, but what is the problem? pg_dump is rock solid, all problems we had in the past, were user mistakes, not technical problems.

Comment: The first thing to check is to see whether that fourth view actually exists in the dump file at all. It's just a text file, so load it up in a text editor and have a look. At the very least, you will then be able to tell whether the problem was in the dump or the restore process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it has 4 views? Or is it that your search_path is set to this schema as well, but the view is actualy in another schema?

```
SELECT * FROM pg_views WHERE schemaname = 'your_schemaname';
```

Comment: Hi frank, Shame on me, i think your diagnostic was true. :(
it looks there is differentiation between my production and development machine. Thanks a lot franks.